# Detect multiple expired Firebase Cloud Messaging Tokens

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm aware that I can know if a token is expired as it's explained in Google Documentation:

https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances

The problem is that I have hundreds of tokens and I want to know every week if any of them is expired. Sending a request for every single token will not be really good. Is there anyway to send one single request with an array of those tokens or anything similar? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to deal with expired tokens is to remove them when you get a "token expired" response when trying to send a message to them. And since you can send a message to many tokens at once, there is no need to perform a separate call for each token.

For a good example of how to do this, see this [snippet from the Cloud Functions example of using FCM through the Admin SDK](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L74-L87):

> ```
>  // Listing all tokens as an array.
>   tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
>   // Send notifications to all tokens.
>   const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
>   // For each message check if there was an error.
>   const tokensToRemove = [];
>   response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
>     const error = result.error;
>     if (error) {
>       console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
>       // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
>       if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
>           error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
>         tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
>       }
>     }
>   });
>   return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
> ```